# How do I test for multidimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, testing, vbscript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to test for an exists of a multidimensional array within my vbscript function, but I am having issues finding the best solution for this.

In my function I'm either excepting a string value or an array of values, the array can either be a single dim or multidimensional.

The problem I'm having is trying to test whether the array is single or multi dim. Is there a predefined way of doing this?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no predefined way; that is: there is no build in function that will return you the amount of dimensions. However, you can build you own.

```
' Returns the amount of dimensions of an array.
' Returns 0 when it is no array
Function GetDimensions(arr)

    Dim dimension, upperBound

    On error resume next
    For dimension = 1 to 255
        upperBound = ubound(arr, dimension)
        If err.Number <> 0 Then Exit for
    Next
    On error goto 0
    GetDimensions = dimension-1
End Function

Dim myArray(41, 42, 43)
MsgBox GetDimensions(myArray) ' Will return 3.
```